# mapping not working for a field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I put the mapping for a field `question_title`, with following:

```
PUT mac/_settings
{
  "mappings": {
    "ask_expert_published_prod": {
      "properties": {
        "question_title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, when i see the mapping for the type through:

```
GET myindex/mytype/_mapping
```

it still shows only type='string' for the field, as following:

```
"question_title": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
```

Was the mapping properly updated on the field. If not, how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial command, remove `_settings` from  the path, since it is only for updating the index settings not mappings.

Simply run this:

```
PUT mac
{
  "mappings": {
    "ask_expert_published_prod": {
      "properties": {
        "question_title": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when i execute the above, it gives error "index already exists".. How do we resolve that? When I give with _settings, it at least goes through and says "acknowledged" : true.

Comment: Simply delete the index first with `DELETE mac`

Comment: No, i dont want to delete the index, as i have lot of data in it. Can't i update it.

Comment: Your indexed data is worthless anyway, since you want to change the mapping you'll have to re-index it all anyway.

Comment: so, @val, i will tell u the exact thing. See i created the index first, then inserted data in one of the types and then i added the analyzer, so want to know if the analyzer will be applied to all the fields of the type by default. If no, how to make sure the newly added analyzer works for appropriate fields.

Comment: The analyzer is only applied at indexing time. The only way to achieve what you want is to delete the index, re-create it as I showed you and then re-index your data.